# Django ASGI vs WSGI performance

Tags: python, django, wsgi, uvicorn, asgi

I am trying to test the performance difference in ASGI and WSGI servers when there are i/o bound functions. I am going to receive streaming responses from 3rd party APIs and then stream them back to client, I am planning on using StreamingHttpResponse of Django. I created two test views, one async one sync, and used time.sleep and asyncio.sleep functions to simulate these web requests that will take a long time to complete.

This is the async view:

```
async def async_view(request):

    async def generate_response_data():
        for i in range(10):
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            yield f'{i} '
    
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
        generate_response_data(), 
        content_type='text/event-stream'
    )
    return response
```

And this is the sync view:

```
def sync_view(request):

    def generate_response_data():
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            yield f'{i} '
    
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
        generate_response_data(), 
        content_type='text/event-stream'
    )

    return response
```

I tried to load test these two endpoints to see the performance difference. I ran sync view with Django's builtin development server and async view with uvicorn. I used apache benchmarking tool for load testing. I used this command `ab -c 500 -n 1000 <endpoint>` meaning 500 concurrent request and total of 1000 requests. ASGI server resulted in 35 requests per second, and WSGI server 42 requests per second.

Every article I read says for this type of i/o bound computations ASGI servers perform better. I dont understand why WSGI performs better in this case.

These are the settings that might be relevant

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'main.asgi.application'

SITE_ID = 1

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend', 
)
```

And this is asgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```